# Making chartjs scrollable on the x-axis

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I want to make a chartjs graph scrollable on the x-axis but only the cavas.
I've tried this solution but makes all of the div scrollable.

```
<div class="chartWrapper">
    <div class="chartAreaWrapper" id="chartAreaWrapper">
        <canvas id="chart-hora" height="500" width="1200"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>

.chartWrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.chartWrapper > canvas {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    pointer-events:none;
}
.chartAreaWrapper {
   width: 600px;
   overflow-x: auto;
}
```

I am showing this chart on mobile app so I only want the canvas to be scrollable and not the whole div which makes the view scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

Place your `canvas` inside a `div` and define their `width` as shown below. Make sure also, to define CSS `overflow: auto` on the wrapping `div` element.

```
<div style="width: 600px; overflow: auto;">
  <canvas id="myChartAxis" width="1500" height="120"></canvas>
</div>
```

To avoid that the `canvas` automatically resizes when the wrapper `div` does, make sure, the chart is not responsive. This needs to be defined inside the chart `options` as follows:

```
options: {
    responsive: false
```

Please have a look at the running code sample below:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChartAxis'), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'WARNINGS',
        data: [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4],
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      },
      {
        label: 'ERRORS',
        data: [4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1],
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 600px; overflow: auto;">
  <canvas id="myChartAxis" width="1500" height="120"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Not making my chart scrollable, the whole page takes the size of the div and the page is the scrollable one.